# PHP Search MySQL database Fatal error

Tags: php, mysql, search

I wrote the query system with android studio and PHP.

My PHP code is as follows.Opened with a web browser but an error occurred.The error message is as follows

Notice: Undefined index: searchQuery in C:\xampp\htdocs\client\beetle_search.php on line 5

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message
>   'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'table 1 where
>   MATCH(name,scientific_name) AGAINST(NULL)' at line 1' in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\client\beetle_search.php:9 Stack trace: #0
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\client\beetle_search.php(9): PDOStatement->execute()
>   1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\client\beetle_search.php on line 9

```
   require_once('config.inc.php');
   $search_query=$_POST['searchQuery'];
   $sql = 'SELECT * from table 1 where MATCH(name,scientific_name) AGAINST(:search_query)';
   $statement = $connection->prepare($sql);
   $statement->bindParam(':search_query', $search_query, PDO::PARAM_STR);
   $statement->execute();
   if($statement->rowCount())
      {
         $row_all = $statement->fetchall(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
         header('Content-type: application/json');
         echo json_encode($row_all);
      }  
   elseif(!$statement->rowCount())
      {
         echo "no rows";
      }
```

Where did you write it wrong? thanks

Comment: `table 1` is that your actual name for the table?

Answer (score 0):

You should add a table name in your query. Update your query

from

```
$sql = 'SELECT * from table 1 where MATCH(name,scientific_name) AGAINST(:search_query)';
```

to

```
$sql = 'SELECT * from table_name where MATCH(name,scientific_name) AGAINST(:search_query)';
```

Also, in order to use MATCH function, you must have the full text index on the column. Otherwise, you will get an error `Can't find FULLTEXT index matching the column list'`. The solution of this problem is given below...

Assuming you are using MyISAM engine, Execute:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ADD FULLTEXT(name);
ALTER TABLE table_name ADD FULLTEXT(scientific_name);
```

Comment: *"You should add a table name in your query."* - They have, but it seems to be named "table" being a mysql reserved word.

Comment: "table 1" is not a reserved keyword, but it does require escaping to use.

Comment: @tadman I take it that that ^ was meant for me. mysql complained about `for the right syntax to use near 'table` << *ahem*.

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: searchQuery in C:\xampp\htdocs\client\beetle_search.php on line 5

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1191 Can't find FULLTEXT index matching the column list' in C:\xampp\htdocs\client\beetle_search.php:9 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\client\beetle_search.php(9): PDOStatement->execute() #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\client\beetle_search.php on line 9

Comment: Please verify either these columns "name" and "scientific_name" exist in your database?

Comment: "name" and "scientific_name" exist  in my database

Comment: @皢嘖嘖 i have updated my answer. Please check it and follow it

Comment: Still an error is declared:

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1191 Can't find FULLTEXT index matching the column list' in C:\xampp\htdocs\client\beetle_search.php:9 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\client\beetle_search.php(9): PDOStatement->execute() #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\client\beetle_search.php on line 9

Comment: @皢嘖嘖 You are still getting same error "General error: 1191 Can't find FULLTEXT index matching the column list' "
Its mean you didn't add fulltext index on your column